# nested ifelse statements and the use of curly braces

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, curly-braces

I got mangled up in how to use curly braces and how to correctly use the nested if else syntax in R studio.

Can you spot my errors?

So there is one main statement checking if a depreciation calculation should occur. And then if it should indeed occur there are 3 possible cases if if it should not occur there is only 1 case.

```
if (depreciation) {
  
  if (is.character(depreciation_percentage) & grepl("automatic_calculation", depreciation_percentage)) {
    # call function
    
    source("calculate_depreciation_percentage_v1.R")
    
    temp_depreciation_percentage = calculate_depreciation_percentage_v1(end_of_life_value_perc_temp, theoretische_afschrijfperiode, restwaarde_bouw_perc,bouwwaarde_perc,perceelwaarde_perc,current_nr_of_years,groeivoet_waarde_perceel)
    
    
  } else is.numeric(depreciation_percentage) {  # so it is assumed the value is numeric
    print("error in automatic depreciation calculation call")
    
    
    browser()
    wearntear_vec = seq(from = 0, to=(depreciation_percentage*size(end_of_life_value_perc_temp,2))-depreciation_percentage , by=depreciation_percentage )
    
    
  } else  {
    #   # should be impossible to arrive here
    # print("error in automatic depreciation calculation call")
    #   browser()
    
    
  }
  
} else if depreciation != 1 {
  # do something
  # wearntear_vec = reeks van nullekes
}
```

Comment: Several points:  You always need parens around the condition in `if`, e.g. `if depreciation != 1` should be `if (depreciation != 1)`.  The `else` part doesn't take a condition, you need a new `if`, e.g. `else if (is.numeric(depreciation_percentage)`. You almost always use `&&` in `if` conditions, e.g. use `if (is.character(depreciation_percentage) && grepl("automatic_calculation", depreciation_percentage))`.

Comment: `if` should take a boolean expression (or what can be cast to boolean, but that should be avoided).  The syntax should always be `if() { } else { }` or `if() { } else if() { } else { }`. Learn the syntax structure basics and then your code will be easier to plan. And use the correct assignment operator in R, which is `<-`. Your variable taking potentially more than one form is problematic. "Should be impossible to arrive here" is an assumption that can easily fail. You really shouldn't be making decisions or assumptions based on the type of a variable. In R, `'1' != 1` evaluates to FALSE.